# How to create a dynamic variable?

Tags: python, callable

I would like to create a variable that will return a different value every-time it is queried.

This is what I have so far:

```
import datetime

def getVal():
    return datetime.datetime.now().time()

TMP_VAR = lambda: getVal()

for a in range(0,10):
    print TMP_VAR()
```

This works and I get:

```
13:06:41.799504
13:06:41.800129
13:06:41.800139
13:06:41.800145
13:06:41.800161
13:06:41.800167
13:06:41.800173
13:06:41.800179
13:06:41.800184
13:06:41.800190
```

How ever, `TMP_VAR` is a function now. Is there a way to get this working in the following fashion?

```
print TMP_VAR
```

Effectively, having a callable function linked to a variable. So everytime I pass my `TMP_VAR` into another function, as an argument it always re-evaluates and happens to be holding a new value (whatever the `getVal()` function is returning at that moment).

Comment: It seems like there is no simple solution to the problem. Having `TMP_VAR()` instead of `TMP_VAR` seems to be a better solution than having to implement a `class` based approach.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a good idea and recommend you to leave it a function since it is more obvious and readable.

But if you really need this – there is the workaround using classes like

```
import datetime


class Timer(object):
    def __call__(self):
        return datetime.datetime.now().time()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self())


TMP_VAR = Timer()
```

now we can write

```
for a in range(0, 10):
    print TMP_VAR
```

or

```
for a in range(0, 10):
    print TMP_VAR()
```

and get the same output.

Comment: This works fine with print, but what if you actually want to use the time as a time object?

Comment: @tobias_k: if we want call function without calling it – we can make property and access on each iteration, i guess, there is no other way

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime

class dynamic_var():

    def __init__(self):
        pass        

    def getVal(self):
        return datetime.datetime.now().time()

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.getVal())

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.getVal())


def main():
    tmp_var = dynamic_var()

    for a in range(0, 50):
        print(tmp_var)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: i like the idea! the only drawback is that you can only return strings this way... (not sure if that is enough for the OP).

Comment: Is there a way to do this through the `__call__` method? So we are not limited to the `__str__` and `__repr__` approaches?

Answer (score 1):

if you do not mind having to create an instance `TMP` of a class `A` first, you could have that behavior with a `property`:

```
from datetime import datetime

class A:
    @property
    def VAR(self):
        return datetime.now().time()

TMP = A()
print(TMP.VAR)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to avoid the `class` based solution for now. I know that this might be solved by faking a `__call__()` method on the variable, but not quite sure how to do that.